# Android Dialog Memory Confusion

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, android-dialog

I am wondering if a `Dialog` is created and then is dismissed or cancelled by calling `dialog.dismiss();` or `dialog.cancel();`

Does it stay in the memory? Or is it removed from the memory?

Comment: No you need to call `dialog=null` to relase its memory. Both method just dismiss dialog from the screen.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#cancel()

> Cancel the dialog. This is essentially the same as calling dismiss(), but it will also call your DialogInterface.OnCancelListener (if registered).

Comment: Thanks but this does not answer my question.